# Getting error while deploying ingress controller in eks

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I am new to eks with fargate ,I am using one sample provided by aws .

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/v1.1.4/docs/examples/2048/2048-namespace.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/v1.1.4/docs/examples/2048/2048-deployment.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/v1.1.4/docs/examples/2048/2048-service.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f 2048-ingress.yaml
```

I am using only fargate profile .After deploying this I am getting one error in ingress-controller .

> E1113 13:48:19.338173       1 controller.go:217]
> kubebuilder/controller "msg"="Reconciler error" "error"="failed to
> build LoadBalancer configuration due to failed to resolve 2 qualified
> subnet with at least 8 free IP Addresses for ALB. Subnets must
> contains these tags: 'kubernetes.io/cluster/thingcenter': ['shared' or
> 'owned'] and 'kubernetes.io/role/elb': ['' or '1']. See
> https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/controller/config/#subnet-auto-discovery for more details. Resolved qualified subnets: '[]'"
> "controller"="alb-ingress-controller"
> "request"={"Namespace":"2048-game","Name":"2048-ingress"}

So according to aws doc I followed these steps as given in this link .
[vpc-subnet](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-vpc-subnet-discovery/)

means ,I have tagged the private subnet with these key value as shown in below image .cluster name is thingcenter .
[image]

Is this the correct place need to tag or anything I missed ,please share your ideas .

Answer (score 0):

How many subnets do you have?

According to the ALB-ingress-controller docs, you must have at least two subnets in different AZ. But based on the screenshot, there is only one subnet.